# Nesting Structs: "borrowed value does not live long enough"

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, borrowing

I've been working on creating a `Table` struct that can resolve to a `Val` trait object along with other data types (`Number` implemented as an example) and can be seen in the Rust Playground [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=use%20std%3A%3Afmt%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Afmt%3A%3AWrite%3B%0A%0Astruct%20Number(f64)%3B%0A%0Astruct%20Table%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20rows%3A%20Vec%3CRow%3C%27a%3E%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Will%20have%20column%20vector%20as%20a%20member%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20%3C%27a%3ETable%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20new(rows%3A%20Vec%3CVec%3CBox%3Cdyn%20Val%3E%3E%3E)%20-%3E%20Table%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20table%20%3D%20Table%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rows%3A%20rows.into_iter().map(%7Cr%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Row%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20parent%3A%20std%3A%3Aptr%3A%3Anull_mut()%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cells%3A%20r%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D).collect()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20parent%20%3D%20%26mut%20table%20as%20*mut%20Table%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20table.rows%20%3D%20table.rows.into_iter().map(%7Cmut%20r%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20r.parent%20%3D%20parent%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20r%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D).collect()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20table%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20Row%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20parent%3A%20*mut%20Table%3C%27a%3E%2C%0A%20%20%20%20cells%3A%20Vec%3CBox%3Cdyn%20Val%3C%27a%3E%3E%3E%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20%3C%27a%3ERow%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20to_str(%26%27a%20self%2C%20buf%3A%20%26mut%20String)%20-%3E%20fmt%3A%3AResult%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20cell_iter%20%3D%20self.cells.iter().enumerate().peekable()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20_parent%20%3D%20unsafe%20%7B%20self.parent.as_ref()%20%7D%3B%20%2F%2F%20Real%20implementation%20will%20need%20parent%20ref%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20while%20let%20Some((idx%2C_c))%20%3D%20cell_iter.next()%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20Real%20implementation%20will%20cycle%20through%20columns%20in%20parent%20struct%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20match%20self.cells.get(idx)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Some(v)%20%3D%3E%20v.to_str(buf)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20None%20%3D%3E%20Ok(())%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3F%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20let%20Some(_)%20%3D%20cell_iter.peek()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20write!(buf%2C%20%22%2C%22)%3F%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Ok(())%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20trait%20Val%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20to_str(%26%27a%20self%2C%20buf%3A%20%26mut%20String)%20-%3E%20fmt%3A%3AResult%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Apub%20trait%20ObjWriter%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20to_str(%26%27a%20self%2C%20buf%3A%20%26%27a%20mut%20String)%20-%3E%20fmt%3A%3AResult%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20%3C%27a%3EObjWriter%3C%27a%3E%20for%20dyn%20Val%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20to_str(%26%27a%20self%2C%20buf%3A%20%26mut%20String)%20-%3E%20fmt%3A%3AResult%20%7B%20self.to_str(buf)%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20%3C%27a%3EVal%3C%27a%3E%20for%20Table%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20to_str(%26%27a%20self%2C%20buf%3A%20%26mut%20String)%20-%3E%20fmt%3A%3AResult%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20write!(buf%2C%20%22(START%20TABLE%3A%22)%3F%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20row_iter%20%3D%20self.rows.iter().peekable()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20while%20let%20Some(r)%20%3D%20row_iter.next()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20r.to_str(buf)%3F%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20write!(buf%2C%20%22%5Cn%22)%3F%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20write!(buf%2C%20%22END%20TABLE)%22)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Number%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20to_str(%26self%2C%20buf%3A%20%26mut%20String)%20-%3E%20fmt%3A%3AResult%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20write!(buf%2C%22%7B%7D%22%2Cself.0)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20%3C%27a%3EVal%3C%27a%3E%20for%20Number%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20to_str(%26self%2C%20buf%3A%20%26mut%20String)%20-%3E%20fmt%3A%3AResult%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.to_str(buf)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20table%20%3D%20Table%3A%3Anew(vec!%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vec!%5BBox%3A%3Anew(Number(0.5))%2CBox%3A%3Anew(Table%3A%3Anew(Vec%3A%3Anew()))%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vec!%5BBox%3A%3Anew(Table%3A%3Anew(Vec%3A%3Anew()))%2CBox%3A%3Anew(Number(0.5))%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%5D)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20buf%20%3D%20String%3A%3Anew()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20table.to_str(%26mut%20buf)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2Cbuf)%0A%7D). I haven't been able to get past this borrow/lifetime issue but the idea is that `Number` and `Table` are both `Val` objects. However, any attempt to write the object to a `String` buffer causes a failure in compilation.

What am I doing wrong here? And what is the rationale for the borrow checker to operate in this way?

```
use std::fmt;
use std::fmt::Write;

struct Number(f64);

struct Table<'a> {
    rows: Vec<Row<'a>>
    // Will have column vector as a member
}

impl <'a>Table<'a> {
    fn new(rows: Vec<Vec<Box<dyn Val>>>) -> Table {
        let mut table = Table {
            rows: rows.into_iter().map(|r| {
                Row {
                    parent: std::ptr::null_mut(),
                    cells: r
                }
            }).collect()
        };

        let parent = &mut table as *mut Table;

        table.rows = table.rows.into_iter().map(|mut r| {
            r.parent = parent;
            r
        }).collect();

        table
    }
}

struct Row<'a> {
    parent: *mut Table<'a>,
    cells: Vec<Box<dyn Val<'a>>>
}

impl <'a>Row<'a> {
    fn to_str(&'a self, buf: &mut String) -> fmt::Result {
        let mut cell_iter = self.cells.iter().enumerate().peekable();
        let _parent = unsafe { self.parent.as_ref() }; // Real implementation will need parent ref
        while let Some((idx,_c)) = cell_iter.next() { // Real implementation will cycle through columns in parent struct
            match self.cells.get(idx) {
                Some(v) => v.to_str(buf),
                None => Ok(())
            }?;
            if let Some(_) = cell_iter.peek() {
                write!(buf, ",")?;
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

pub trait Val<'a> {
    fn to_str(&'a self, buf: &mut String) -> fmt::Result;
}

pub trait ObjWriter<'a> {
    fn to_str(&'a self, buf: &'a mut String) -> fmt::Result;
}

impl <'a>ObjWriter<'a> for dyn Val<'a> {
    fn to_str(&'a self, buf: &mut String) -> fmt::Result { self.to_str(buf) }
}

impl <'a>Val<'a> for Table<'a> {
    fn to_str(&'a self, buf: &mut String) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(buf, "(START TABLE:")?;
        let mut row_iter = self.rows.iter().peekable();
        while let Some(r) = row_iter.next() {
            r.to_str(buf)?;
            write!(buf, "\n")?;
        }
        write!(buf, "END TABLE)")
    }
}

impl Number {
    fn to_str(&self, buf: &mut String) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(buf,"{}",self.0)
    }
}

impl <'a>Val<'a> for Number {
    fn to_str(&self, buf: &mut String) -> fmt::Result {
        self.to_str(buf)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let table = Table::new(vec![
        vec![Box::new(Number(0.5)),Box::new(Table::new(Vec::new()))],
        vec![Box::new(Table::new(Vec::new())),Box::new(Number(0.5))],
    ]);

    let mut buf = String::new();
    table.to_str(&mut buf);
    println!("{}",buf)
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `table` does not live long enough
   --> src/main.rs:98:5
    |
92  |       let table = Table::new(vec![
    |  ____________________________-
93  | |         vec![Box::new(Number(0.5)),Box::new(Table::new(Vec::new()))],
94  | |         vec![Box::new(Table::new(Vec::new())),Box::new(Number(0.5))],
95  | |     ]);
    | |_____- cast requires that `table` is borrowed for `'static`
...
98  |       table.to_str(&mut buf);
    |       ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
99  |       println!("{}",buf)
100 |   }
    |   - `table` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Comment: I think the `'static` in the error message comes from `Box<dyn Foo>` being a shorthand for `Box<dyn Foo + 'static>`. I tried adding `+ 'a` to your dyn boxes, but I got a [different error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eed40ed52ac555cdc84659c509d1b335) related to lifetimes. Not sure this helps, but maybe it nudges you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for playing :) I've tried many different variations of lifetime declarations and am still unsuccessful! I've actually got the exact same error in another version of this but neither works. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Your parent pointers are invalidated as soon as `new` returns.

Comment: You've got way too many `'a`s here, it's very confusing. You almost never want `&'a self` in a function parameter, so those would be the first to get rid of. The problem is it's tricky to remove lifetimes in code that uses `unsafe` *especially* when the code is already known to be unsound, as I already pointed out this code is. How are you going to deal with the problem that as soon as `table` moves, all the pointers to it are immediately invalidated? Once you have that figured out, we can talk about how to prove it correct with lifetimes.

Comment: This version, for example, compiles, but is wrong: [click for **undefined behavior**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8ad3e3802fac4306ecf0856e9734d00e)

Comment: Thanks @trentcl, I didn't know the pointer was invalidated once `new()` returns, I might have to make sure a `&Table` reference is passed as an argument to each Rows method.

Answer (score 1):

I did as suggested [trentcl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3650362/trentcl), noting that my pointers would be invalidated on move, I refactored my code so that any `Row` methods would take the parent table's reference as the first parameter. Then I removed all the `<'a>` followed the compiler errors until it worked.

So the whole problem was allowing the lifetimes to get out of control and using unsafe methods to get parent references. Go figure...